# Is it possible to max a companion's approval rating?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I've been romacing Solas and making sure every single thing I say garners his approval. Recently, I noticed these approval messages stopped for him. I'm still getting them for the rest of the party, but his no longer triggers on things that are common for him to approve (like asking him questions about the Fade or finding Elven artifacts).

Is it possible to max out an approval? Of do the approvals stop for that person once you've entered into a romance with him/her? Or have I encountered some kind of bug?

Answer (score 2):

Once you are in a locked romance, they will no longer gain or lose approval, because a romance is the highest approval there it is and it can never be changed unless you break it up with him.

Answer (score 1):

I believe so. I just noticed this myself as I did a personal quest for him and learned one of the dialogue choices netted a great approval but I didn't get it. Once it's maxed I think you go through a cutscene with them and they call you their friend or something along those lines.

As I believe I just maxed out Dorian, and earlier Solas, and then Cassandra before him.

Answer (score 0):

I can possibly confirm this. I tried every possible judgment of SPOILER and never received approval.

Also just finished Cassandra's seeker quest and didn't get approval no matter what dialogue I chose.

Answer (score -1):

it could be a bug my cole has the same problem and I played the game twice rest started cause cole approval froze after a certain point, I'm at the point where he warm, not friendly according to dragon age wiki approval. so I think it a bug